# Autofill Google Forms fields based on entering a serial number

Tags: google-forms

I want to use Google Forms to do the following

At a student help desk, a student brings an iPad with a cracked screen.  The HD assistant would scan the iPad's barcode (serial number) into a Google form.

Once the serial # is entered into that field, other fields populate automatically from a sheet with data (serial#, fname, lname, school, email, ...)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need a web apps in order to communicate with server (the sheet with data).