# Autofill specific fields of google form using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am looking to autofill specific fields of a Google Form when the user fills a specific field. Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559556/autofill-google-forms-fields-based-on-entering-a-serial-number). It means when I input the serial number, the name associated with this number should be pulled from the sheet to the Google form field. Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849716/auto-fill-or-automate-a-google-form) that addresses form autofill. I am trying to show a dialog box on the Google form interface using `onOpen trigger`:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var serial = ui.prompt('Enter Your Serial Number', 'Please enter your serial number:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (serial.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var enteredSerial = serial.getResponseText();
    console.log(enteredSerial);
  }
}
```

Ideally, when I open the [form link](https://forms.gle/6B44Ae7Jhx6fpqha7), an input box should pop up and I would be able to fill in the serial number in this dialog box:

[image: DialogBox]

Then we search for this serial number in the sheet and pull the name that corresponds to it into the second field of Google form. But the **issue is**, that the `dialog box does not show up on the viewform interface` of Google form. Any guidance or workaround would be much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate Google Form using Google App Script on Form open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599312/populate-google-form-using-google-app-script-on-form-open)

Comment: By reviewing that question, you'll see that your statement `that the dialog box does not show up on the viewform interface of Google form` is expected. You may also review it at [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), where it states that `* The open event for Google Forms does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but rather when an editor opens the form to modify it.`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes the event only occurs when an editor opens the form, that's why I am seeking a workaround. The question that you provided a link to, is different because it uses a web app, I want to avoid that.

Comment: Apologies. I did not know that you `want to avoid` web apps, as it was not stated in the question. That's actually the workaround that I thought of as well. If I find any other thing that could potentially work as a workaround for you, I'll post it here to help out.

Comment: `But the issue is...` May I respectfully suggest a different way of looking at the scenario. You must build **TWO** distinct Google forms. The first form ("FormA") is designed to **collect** a serial number - it is short, perhaps two questions only. The second form ("FormB") is designed to **supply** (by pre-fill) information in specific fields based on the serial number - this is a longer form containing questions for all the "specific fields". If necessary "FormB" could also include any supplementary questions that relate to the submission. I have outlined the workflow below.

Comment: A possible workflow might be: 1) user submits a serial number in "FormA"; 2) "FormA" is linked to a spreadsheet; 3) spreadsheet contains "database" of information about serial numbers; 4) each "FormA" submission triggers a script; 5) the script queries the serial number in the database and collects relevant information about the serial number item **AND** creates a pre-fill link for containing that information **Form"B"**; 6) user clicks the pre-fill link, "FormB" opens, all the relevant fields are pre-populated by the link; user can answer non-prefill questions (if any) and submit the form.

Comment: I suggest that you read: [How do I populate checkbox google form responses from another google form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513724/1330560). Ignore the references to checkboxes; the question (and answer) explain how the first form collects information, compiles the information via a pre-fill link, which enables the second form to be submitted. Your scenario is similar to this.